# Toggle button on a table field

Tags: buttons, tables, toggle

I'm thinking of using a toggle button to publish/unpublish a product in a table field. What is your view on using a toggle button and keeping a field clickable in a table?

Answer (score 1):

Actions in table's rows are quite common, as each row represents some actionable domain entity.
One thing you should care of is the data in a row provides enough information on taking decision of making an action. So a user shouldn't dive into details to make a decision and turn back to perform an action.

You can see live example of this approach on the following image:
[image]